# How to make an exe for my united iphone application

Tags: iphone, exe, unity-game-engine

I created a game using unity iphone.there are six characters in my game,first you click one character,the character was selected, and then you click a target position,the selected character will move to your target position. this function work well in the unity3d iphone engine. however when i build an exe file for it, although the exe file can be opened in window xp, I can only selected the character,the rest operation can't work.I don't know what cause this problem, can you give me some advise.
    My build step is below:
In Unity…
Select “File” from the top menu.
Select “Build Settings”
Select “PC & Mac Standalone” under the platforms column (lower left)
On the combo box labelled “Target Platform” select “Windows”
Click “Switch Platform” button (lower left, 1st button).
When all the assets have been reconverted to suit the new platform, you’ll be ready to click the build button (lower right).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to be more clear on your problem.

First of, did you added Input controls for Mouse control? If not, go to Input settings and add it. There you can basically define which input events (mouse, keyboard, joystick, touchscreen) are mapped to what actions.

For example, if you want mouse and keyboard movement, you have to add Horizontal and Vertical axis twice. Once for mouse input, one for keyboard input. I guess it's same for iPhone, since it's touchscreen you probably have to add some kind of axis or code which will handle it correctly. Can't tell much more, as I don't have iPhone neither the unity license for it.

Second off, your question would be more appropiate to be asked at http://answers.unity3d.com/, which is unity's official Stockexchange version for asking/answering questions and there are only unity developers there.